# Ansible using Kerberos fails on Windows host if Basic authentication is not enabled

Tags: ansible, kerberos, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to configure a Windows Server 2019 host with Ansible, using Kerberos as the transport protocol for WinRM. I had initially run the ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 script on this host while testing and once I had gotten Kerberos to work I decided to disable Basic auth on the host.

However as soon as I disable Basic auth on the host - Kerberos also stops working. I'm using this command to flip Basic auth between $true and $false:

`Set-Item -Path "WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic" -Value $false`

The Ansible vars I'm using for the playbook run are:

```
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_become: yes
ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
ansible_winrm_kinit_mode: managed
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true
ansible_winrm_scheme: https
```

As soon as I turn Basic auth off, authentication fails with the following message:

**"msg": "kerberos: the specified credentials were rejected by the server"**

Can anyone help me understand what role Basic auth is still playing in the authentication process even though I'm using Kerberos for transport?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the initialization of the host that we do with VMware, as restarting the machine solves the issue.